# I am constructing a breadcrumb system in PHP and though my code is correct it is not displaying on the page

Tags: php

I am working on my finals and though this was not covered in my internet commerce class it is something I have been interested in having in my website. I have read through a couple of postings on here about building the function and it is not throwing any errors, but the crumbs are not displaying at all on the page. I went back and did some more research and uncovered a `$upToNowCrumbs` array, but again it did nothing to help display the crumbs on the pages.

Here is the code for the function itself (file is located in `header.php`):

```
<?php
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' &raquo; ', $home ='Overview')
{
    $path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
    $base_url = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    $breadcrumbs = array("<a href=\"$base_url\">$home</a>");
    $key_set = array_keys($path);

    $last = end($key_set);

    $upToNowCrumbs = array();

    foreach($path AS $x => $crumb)
    {
        $upToNowCrumbs[] = $crumb;
        $title = ucwords(str_replace(array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));
        if ($x != $last)
        {
            $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href=\"$base_url".implode('/', $upToNowCrumbs)."\">$title</a>';
        }

        else
        {
            $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
        }
    }

    return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
}
?>
```

and here is how I am calling the function in the site itself (file is located in site_header.php):

```
<section class="bread">
<article class='admin-bread'>
    <?php breadcrumbs(' > '); ?>
</article>
```

I know we are not supposed to edit questions, but I am not altering anything. I forgot that by using the `$upToNowCrumbs` generates a error (sorry I am tired)

```
Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\finals\inc\header.php on line 24

Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\finals\inc\header.php on line 24
```

Comment: but your codes correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href=\"$base_url".implode('/', $upToNowCrumbs)."\">$title</a>';
```

should be

```
    $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="'.$base_url.implode('/', $upToNowCrumbs).'">'.$title.'</a>';
```

Comment: This got rid of the division by zero error, but I am still not displaying the breadcrumbs.

Comment: try it now, i've corrected vars inside string

Comment: It is displaying, but now I am now seeing new problems. `Home > $title > Index` is displaying on the screen and if I click on the $title link it tosses a 403 error and the address bar spits out localhost/$base_urlfinals as the address. Another issue is that I don't want it going completely down to root which it is if I click on Home. I need that to default to the home page of my finals.

Comment: Wait, this cannot be the right answer, you are modifying the code, and his code is correct remember!

Comment: yes and I got it working. I had a single quote in the wrong place, but now it all works. His code was correct, I just was missing the small stuff. now it renders out Home > Finals which is as close is it will be until it is on the domain, right now it is running local.

Answer (score 3):

You have to echo breadcrumbs, right now you are just returning it.

```
 <?php echo breadcrumbs(' > '); ?>
```

Comment: lol you are correct on that one... it is the small things in life that kill us. I did change it so it has the echo, but now I have a ugly little error so I can't tell if that fixed it.

Comment: ts. just gave an answer with the fix to the new issue

Comment: yup I see that and it corrected the issue and I had to force close chrome and now I see the crumbs, however it is a full trail of crumbs which goes to the root of the host, and oddly enough it is also returning this one:

    `Home > $page_title > Index`